# pylint vscode unable to import own module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

**Context**

I have a project in vscode with following file structure:

```
main_folder/
  .vscode/
    settings.json
  src/
    my_package/
      part1/
        __init__.py
        code1.py
      part2/
        __init__.py
        code2.py
    __init__.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    test_code1.py
.env
```

The `settings.json` file is written as follows:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9",
    "python.envFile": ".env",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"]
}
```

The `.env` file is written as follows:

```
PYTHONPATH=./src
```

**Problem**

In `test_code1.py`, I'm trying to import code1 this way:

```
import my_package.code1
```

And I get an error: `Unable to import 'my_package.code1' pylint(import-error)`

However, this works:

```
import src.my_package.code1
```

But I would like to go for the first option.

Any good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an absolute path to `python.envFile`. It should be:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

And in the `.env` file, you can add this:

```
PYTHONPATH=src
```